# convert an nsbutton title to a double value

Tags: macos, swift3, double, nsbutton

i have an nsbutton.
this button get a title like this:
**22,00 EUR**

Code for that:

```
var sum = 22.0
button.title = String(format: "%.02f EUR", locale: Locale.current, arguments: [sum])
```

now i would like to calculate with the value, which was set as a title for the button.

can i save the value 22.0 as a hidden value into the button?
or is there an elegant way to convert the button title string "22,00 EUR" in a Double?

Comment: Don't pass a value through the title of a button.

Comment: `button.title = "\(Double(2200)) EUR"`

Comment: save your value in a property (of an object) but not on a button title. Think of multilanguage usage...